# React Laravel Project - Only URL is changin but page is not rendering

Tags: reactjs, laravel, react-redux, react-router-dom

I have this weird thing in my project....

When I click on a lin kin header.js, the page changes smoothly.
But the links in breadcrumb, change the URL only and the page does not render. I have to refresh the page to render it.

My index.js looks like

```
<Router>                        
   <Header/>
     <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/admin" component={withRouter(AdminUsers)} />
         <Route exact path="/" component={withRouter(Home)} />
         <Route exact path="/about" component={withRouter(About)} />
         <Route exact path="/register" component={withRouter(Register)} />
         <Route exact path="/login" component={withRouter(Login)} />
         <Route exact path="/reset" component={withRouter(Reset)} />
         <Route exact path="/profileDoctorCreate" component={withRouter(ProfileDoctorCreate)} />
         <Route exact path="/profileDoctorupdate" component={withRouter(ProfileDoctorUpdate)} />
         <Route exact path="/profileHospitalCreate" component={withRouter(ProfileHospitalCreate)} />
         <Route exact path="/profileHospitalUpdate" component={withRouter(ProfileHospitalUpdate)} />
         <Route exact path="/profilelist" component={withRouter(Profilelist)} />
       </Switch>
    <Footer/>
</Router>
```

the breadcrumb is

```
<nav aria-label="breadcrumb"> 
   <ol className="breadcrumb">
    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/profileDoctorCreate">DR Profile Update</Link></li>
    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/profileDoctorUpdate">DR Profile Update</Link></li>
    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/profileHospitalCreate">HO Profile Update</Link></li>
    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/profileHospitalUpdate">HO Profile Update</Link></li>
    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/profilelist">Profile List</Link></li>
    <li className="breadcrumb-item"><Link to="/admin">Admin</Link></li>
   </ol>
</nav>
```

I am using react-router-dom and the backend is of Laravel.
the web.php looks like

```
Route::get( '/{path?}', function(){
  return view( 'app' );
} )->where('path', '.*');
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this.

I was wrapping my compnents in  which was causing the issue. I perhaps copied it online.

Hope no one does the same mistake.